# Looping through Array of Containers

Tags: javascript, createjs

I'm trying to get containers within containers that I've stored in a Containers array. Sounds confusing, so here's the code:

First I make individual containers to store BMP and label for People and Animals: (I will make a new container for each instance of a NPC because I want individual control over BMP and associated Label).

```
peopleContainer.addChild(peopleBMP, peopleLabel);
animalContainer.addChild(animalBMP, animalLabel);   
animalContainer2.addChild(animalBMP, animalLabel);
```

I then assign them names and IDs:

```
peopleContainer.name = "peopleContainer1";
peopleContainer.id = 0;

animalContainer.name = "animalContainer1";
animalContainer.id = 1;

animalContainer2.name = "animalContainer2"; 
animalContainer2.id = 2;
```

I then want to create Containers that store these individual containers:

```
ContainerOfPeople = new createjs.Container();   
ContainerOfPeople.name = "Container Of People";
ContainerOfPeople.id = 0;
ContainerOfPeople.addChild(peopleContainer);

ContainerOfAnimals = new createjs.Container();  
ContainerOfAnimals.name = "Container Of Animals";
ContainerOfAnimals.id = 1;
ContainerOfAnimals.addChild(animalContainer, animalContainer2);
```

I then add those big containers to an array

```
NPC_Array.push(ContainerOfPeople, ContainerOfAnimals);
```

Now, I'd like to loop through the array of big containers, and get the individual IDs of the containers within the big containers... That way I can check their individual distances to see which is closest to the player...

```
function checkDistance2() {
   //loop through Containers Array [ContainerOfAnimals, ContainerOfPeople]... 
   for (var index = 0; index < NPC_Array.length; index++) {
        console.log(NPC_Array[index].children[0].name);         
   }            
}
```

This gives the output:

```
peopleContainer1 
animalContainer2
```

It seems to be working, but it's skipping over the first animalContainer (name `animalContainer1`) within ContainerOfAnimals. Why is that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're not iterating over the array at `NPC_Array[index].children`. This fixes that:

```
function checkDistance2() {
   for (var index = 0; index < NPC_Array.length; index++) {
       for (var j = 0; j < NPC_Array[index].children.length; j++) {
           console.log(NPC_Array[index].children[j].name); 
       }
   }            
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/6HGY9

Comment: Why not? animalContainer's name is `animalContainer1`, but the actual container variable's name is still animalContainer... unless the variable name reference is somehow changed when I change the `name` property?

Comment: I figured out why the animalContainer1 wasn't being added... I originally thought I could just create a new copy of animalContainer1 into animalContainer2 just by doing `animalContainer2 = animalContainer;`...  Just realized I needed to do `animalContainer2.clone(animalContainer);` to make a copy

Comment: Assignment only copies primitives, not objects. Probably downvoted because these are very basic JavaScript questions/mistakes, and unlikely to be useful to others in the future because they're not really searchable or generically posed. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149138/133242.